# Limit NSURLConnection data rate? (Bandwidth throttling)

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, nsurlconnection, bandwidth-throttling

Is there a way to limit the bandwidth used by an NSURLConnection, or I'm forced to use CFNetwork methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's not pretty (it works according to [this mailing list post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/137445-limit-data-rate-with-an-nsurlconnection.html)):

- Start NSURLConnection on a background thread (you'll have to set up a run loop).
- Sleep in `-connection:didReceiveData:`.
- Forward your data to the main thread in a thread-safe fashion.

The third bulletpoint is a little tricky to get right if the delegate is a `UIViewController`, but something like this should work provided `delegate` is `__weak` or `__unsafe_unretained`:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:...];
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(notifyDelegateDidReceiveData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)notifyDelegateDidReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
  assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
  [delegate myConnectionWrapper:self didReceiveData:data];
}
```

Calculating how long to sleep for is non-trivial because you may wish to account for TCP/IP overheads, but `[data length]+100` may be about right.

If you have multiple connections and you want to throttle the combined bandwidth, put them all on the *same* background thread/run loop (see `-performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`).

For the CFNetwork version, I'm guessing you've read [this post on Cocoa with Love](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/04/network-data-requirements-on-iphone-os.html).

Comment: Whoa, thank you for the amazing answer! As you said it's not pretty but I will try and see if it works reliably, if not I'm gonna stick with CFNetwork. Thank you again!

Comment: @tc The NSURLConnection method doesn't really limit the download rate instead its going to slow down the storing of data in local buffer! we can't limit the data passed to `-connection:didReceiveData:` method. Can we limit the data read from socket, which is passed to `-connection:didReceiveData:` in some way?

Comment: @bikram990 I was hoping that it would do `read()` and `-connection:didReceiveData:` in the same thread. If not, then I'd see if ASIHttpRequest or AFNetworking supported rate-limiting; it might not be difficult to add support for it either.

Comment: @tc **ASIHttpRequest** can limit the rate as it uses `CFNetwork` directly but **AFNetworking** can't because it uses `NSURLConnection`. I looked into source of **AFNetworking**, it seems that it can limit the upload rate but i couldn't find a public interface for that in their examples.

Comment: @tc I'm a beginner in objective c. May be i missed something but AFAIK `NSURLConnection` can't limit download rate.