# Does RestKit support bandwidth limits?

Tags: cocoa, post, restkit, rate-limiting, bandwidth-throttling

I'm using RestKit to POST large files and it is working well enough that it is using up about as much bandwidth as is available. How do I limit the data rate? I am sending one file at a time so I can't reduce concurrency any further.

I know an easy way -- Wait between sending files. However, the files are large so there are long periods where everything else gets starved for bandwidth. Any ideas on how to limit the bandwidth consumed while uploading a single file? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of RestKit are you using? And perhaps limiting bandwith would be more a NSURLConnection, maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314144/limit-nsurlconnection-data-rate-bandwidth-throttling

Comment: RestKit 0.10.2. I see that it has been updated in 0.20 and that RKClient has been replaced and now uses AFNetworking. It isn't obvious how to limit bandwidth with AFNetworking either -- any pointers?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no official way to do something like this, most of the solutions seems hackish to me :/

Answer (score 0):

RestKit 0.2 uses AFNetworking for network requests. It supports bandwidth throttling through http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Protocols/AFMultipartFormData.html#//api/name/throttleBandwidthWithPacketSize:delay:
I've not tried this myself, but you could. Let us know the result, please!

But then again, if you're using 0.10 you'll have hard times switching to 0.2 quickly. But I think it should worth it.